# Неверное значение в переменных, хотя в них имеется другое число (Java/Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio

Я объявил изначально эти переменные

```
private String level = "0", action = "0";
private int step = 1;
```

Меняю их значение

```
swipe.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(LevelActivity.this) {

            public void onSwipeTop() {

                action = "8";
                level(); //вызываю метод, который "обрабатывает" действия
                pStatus = 0;
                step++;


            }});}
```

Обрабатываю значения, всё работает хорошо

```
  public void level() {
System.out.println("***CURRENT NUMBER IS " + level + step + action + "***"); 
       //Выводит 114 и другое, все ок
        switch (level + step + action) {
//LEVEL 1
            case "114":
                instructionsTV.setText(getString(R.string.swipe_up_1));
                step = 2;
                break;
            case "138":
                instructionsTV.setText(getString(R.string.swipe_bottom1));
                step = 3;
                break;
            case "152":
                instructionsTV.setText(getString(R.string.swipe_up_1));
                step = 4;
                break;

            default:
                detect = 1;
myQuittingDialogBox.show();
        }

    }
```

Но проблема заключается в другом. Я вывожу цифры в **LogCat** через другой метод

```
 public static void  onDoubleTap() {
        new LevelActivity().singletap();}


    public  void singletap() {
        System.out.println("***CURRENT NUMBER IS " + level + step + action + "***");
    }
```

Выводится следующее: I/System.out: ***CURRENT NUMBER IS 010***

Хотя значения у переменных другие

Comment: приведите весь код активити, непонятно где объявляете, когда вызываете

Comment: Это адекватное поведение. Вы создаете инстанс класса и выводите значение его полей. У Вас два класса, в каждом из которых свои значения. PS: советую почитать основы java.

Comment: Большое спасибо